# Unable to create jira issue using python

Tags: python, jira

```
from jira.client import JIRA
jira_options={"http://ontrack-internal.mycomapny.com"}
jira=JIRA(options=jira_options,basic_auth=("user","pass"))
new_issue=jira.create_issue(project={"key":"SSET QA OPS (SSETOPS)"},summary="k-+s",description="please look into this",issuetype={"name":"task"})
```

I don't know what i am doing wrong

Comment: What's the error message?

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/rahsingh/.PyCharmCE2017.3/config/scratches/scratch_10.py", line 3, in <module>
    jira=JIRA(options=jira_options,basic_auth=("user","pass"))
  File "C:\Users\rahsingh\PycharmProjects\ATI\venv\lib\site-packages\jira\client.py", line 299, in __init__
    self._options.update(options)
ValueError: dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 31; 2 is required

Comment: Please let me know the correct code for creating an issue with jira rest api and python

Comment: summary is the headline of the issue, what 'k-+s' means? also for 'key' i think you should use just the short 10-char key (SSETOPS in your case)

Comment: i gave two strings in k and s so wrote like that,it can be anything